# Objective C - SplitViewController not loading the Master UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

```
rootController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
rootController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
masterController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
[masterController setCdw:cdw];
detailsViewController *detailsController = [[detailsViewController alloc] init];

detailsController.delegate = masterController;
masterController.detailsDelegate = detailsController;

// MASTER CONTROLLER
UINavigationController * master = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: masterController];

// DETAIL CONTROLLER
UINavigationController * detail = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: detailsController];

rootViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: master, detail, nil];
rootController.delegate = detailsController;
self.window.rootviewController = rootController;
```

This is the function i use to create the master-detail split view which works perfectly when ran on an iPad simulator, for example the master's viewDidLoad method is called and then after the detail's viewDidLoad method is called. So far everything is fine.

The issue is when launched on an iPhone the behaviour of the split view is bizarre, for one the master view is never called (the viewDidLoad method is never called) and instead solely the detail view is loaded. If i remove the 'detail' UINavigationController from the array then the master view is loaded and then issues arise as expected since the detail view is missing. But i cannot figure out why the iPad simulator works perfectly and the iPhone simulator does not even call the master view...

Comment: What happens if you use `[rootViewController showViewController:master sender:nil];` and `[rootViewController showDetailViewController:detail sender:nil];` instead of setting `.viewControllers` directly?

Comment: Is the iPhone you're testing with using iOS7 or earlier?

Comment: When i change the line:

`rootViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: master, detail, nil];`

With

`[rootViewController showViewController:master sender:nil];
[rootViewController showDetailViewController:detail sender:nil];`

it gives me:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: and also _Splitview controller <UISplitViewController: 0x7a9f9600> is expected to have a view controller at index 0 before it's used!_

Comment: Getting the same Error. u found any solution?